# Type casting when exceeding the limit

Tags: c++, c, casting, type-conversion

I want to multiply two `int` numbers and, in order to prevent exceeding the `int` limit (2147483647), the result is saved in a `long long` variable. So, I try this piece of code:

```
int a, b;
long long result = a * b;
```

and **it doesn't work!** If `a=50000` and `b=50000` then `result=-1794967296`.

Therefore, I have to apply a type casting to `a` and `b`:

```
int a, b;
long long result = (long long)a * (long long)b;
```

Why is it necessary to apply a type casting in this case?

Note: I don't want to change the data type of `a` and `b`, I need to keep them as `int`.

Comment: Because an `int` multiplied by an `int` is still an `int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `a` and `b` are `int`, their product `a*b` is `int` also. But the product is so big that it overflows and you get an incorrect value.The cast is needed so that the product is also `long long`.

By the way, you don't need to cast both operands. Just one is enough:

```
long long result = a * (long long)b;
```

The other one is *promoted* to `long long` also.  See [this online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c00b553086273ea29b9ef42954a73a92-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68).

By the way, prefer C++-style cast over C-style cast:

```
long long result = a * static_cast<long long>(b);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In an arithmetic expression like `a * b` the compiler looks at the types of the arguments and does the corresponding operation. In this case, both `a` and `b` have type `int`, so the compiler multiples the two `int` values, producing a result of type `int`.

To do the calculation at higher precision, one or both of the arguments must have that precision. So you need to change either `a` or `b` (or both) to `long long` in order to get the compiler to generate code that multiplies two `long long` values.

Answer (score 2):

Because the **result of a `int` * `int` multiplication is an `int` itself**, so the result is an int that is then converted to a long long but overflow has already occurred.

But if you cast the a and b variables to a `long long` before the multiplication (or just one of them), the result is a `long long`.
Remember:

```
int * int --> int 
long long * long long --> long long
long long * int --> long long
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cast both `a` and `b`. Just `a` is enough.

Just think that you're the compiler and you're asked:
take two things, `combine` them and `place` them over there.

That's two instructions: `combine` and `place`.
And the second one should not care about the first one
if you're using a speedy language like `C`.

What does help you is that `combine` cares about what it
combines. Now you just need to state it clearly and cast
one of the operands to `long long`.

You might think that `place` could be smarter, and it
actually should be smarter, but there also should be
a clearly defined limit to how smart it should be,
otherwise we get that story from Space Odyssey 2001 :).